# Return value of event triggered function

Tags: javascript, function, button, listener

I'm simply implementing a function that is called after a button is clicked. The function works fine, but i'm not capable of making it return a value and assign it to a variable.

I would like to call the function `play` once the button is clicked, and then return the values (as shown in the code) to a variable, in order to make them accessible for future uses.

I've already implemented all I need (i'm messing around with the web audio api) and it works fine, the   `test1` variable "embeddeds" the `osc` and `lfo` variables and i'm able to access them outside the function.

```
var ac = new AudioContext();

function play(){
     var osc = ac.createOscillator();
     var lfo = ac.createOscillator();
     osc.frequency.value=1000;
     console.log("Clicked!!");
     returnedObject={};
     returnedObject["value1"] = osc;
     returnedObject["value2"] = lfo;
     return returnedObject;
};

var test1= play();
var test= document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", play);
```

The `test1` variable contains what i need, but the `test` variable doesn't.

How can i assign to a variable the returned object of a function after it's been called by an event?

What i'm getting right now if i use `test.value1` is an `undefined` error, this makes me think that the assignment of the variable failed.

Comment: `addEventListener` does **not** return the callback result, since it's not synchronous. It just binds the event, you should assign the value directly in your `play` function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener returns `undefined` by design, and is meant to do so.

Comment: what do you expect? the `play` for the event handler isn't called until the button is clicked. javascript won't block.

Comment: @briosheje So I should create a variable, pass it to the play function when it's called by the listener and then assign the value inside of the play function, right?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio no, you should just assign the value to the global `test` variable **inside** your `play` callback.

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Instead of polluting global namespace I`ll suggest you to use closure. See code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

You can do this, but you have to consider that the value is `undefined` until the button is clicked.

```js
var ac = new AudioContext();

function play(){
     var osc = ac.createOscillator();
     var lfo = ac.createOscillator();
     console.log("Clicked!!");
     returnedObject={};
     returnedObject["value1"] = osc;
     returnedObject["value2"] = lfo;
     return returnedObject;
};

var test;
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", () => (test = play()));
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">click me</button>
```

---

In order to perform functions with the data you probably want to create a middle function that takes care of whatever work you want done:

```js
var ac = new AudioContext();

function play(){
     var osc = ac.createOscillator();
     var lfo = ac.createOscillator();
     console.log("Clicked!!");
     returnedObject={};
     returnedObject["value1"] = osc;
     returnedObject["value2"] = lfo;
     return returnedObject;
};

function middle(fn) {
return function() {
let data = fn();

//do something
console.dir(data);
}
}

document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", middle(play));
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">click me</button>
```

---

Alternatively you can create a Constructor that holds onto the data, thus allowing you to add methods to the Constructor for manipulation at a later time:

```js
function Player() {
  let proto = {};
  proto.ac = new AudioContext();
  proto.data = [];
  proto.play = function() {
    var osc = proto.ac.createOscillator();
    var lfo = proto.ac.createOscillator();
     proto.data.push({
      value1: osc,
      value2: lfo
    });
 proto.latest = proto.data[proto.data.length-1];
        console.log("Clicked!!", proto.latest);
  };
  

  return proto;
}

const myPlayer = new Player();

document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", myPlayer.play);
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">click me</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I'm aware that my value will be undefined if i do not click the button! Very smart solution, i didn't think about using a lambda expression and then assign the value to my variable, really smart!

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener`, by design, is meant to **don't** return anything at all (thanks @AmitJoki for mentioning that) [as you can read in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

The relevant part is (excerpt of [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Getting_Data_Into_and_Out_of_an_Event_Listener))

> Event listeners only take one argument, the Event Object, which is automatically passed to the listener, and the **return value is ignored**

The reason behind that is that `addEventListener` is just meant to **register an event**, not to handle the result of it.

If you want to assign the result to the global variable `test`, you should just do that **inside** your `play` callback.

Comment: "is meant to return undefined", no. It doesn't `return` anything by the virtue of which the value is *undefined*. It won't have`return undefined` in its function body.

Comment: @AmitJoki Not sure whether it has, but MDN mentions `undefined` in the return section. Indeed, it should **not** return at all as far as I can tell, I'm just trying to stay as close as possible to what is said here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Return_value . I will edit the answer, anyway, since your point makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use closure instead.
Try something like this.

```
 // closure
        function audioControl() {

            var ac = new AudioContext();
            var props = {
                value1: ac.createOscillator(),
                value2: ac.createOscillator()
            };
            // function play
            function play() {
                osc.frequency.value = 1000;
                console.log("Clicked!!");
                props.value1 = "_modified_value";
                props.value2 = "_modified_value";
            }
            return {
                props: props,
                play: play
            }
        };

        var test1 = audioControl();
        var test = document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", test1.play);

        // now you can get values anywhere anytime using
        // -- test1.props.value1;
```